# What's more persistent, LocalStorage or PHP Sessions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, local-storage

- Let's say 100% of my users are on local storage enabled browsers.
- using either mobile or desktop devices
- to store a 50 character string (that contains no sensitive info)
- considering, browser updates, cache restrictions etc...

Which is **most likely** to still hold this value 100 days later, long-expiry sessions or localstorage?

Comment: `localStorage`. Wipe the cookies and your PHP session is not associated with the user any more.

Comment: @Rob The browser will eventually clean out localstorage data too, and the user may clean it out themselves just like cookies.

Comment: maybe @deceze is wrong, and a prediction can be made, but I think that only an A/B test on your particular website would tell the truth (and whether it's worthwhile to bother)

Answer (score 6):

*You* have complete control over how long a session is alive on your server.
You have *no* control whatsoever over anything that goes on on the client. That includes LocalStorage and the session cookie needed for the session. Either way, it entirely depends on the client, there's no prediction you can make here either way.

Comment: Surely 'typical behaviour' of both the user and the browser will affect this? For example a mobile browser, are they more likely to flush one or the other to free up space?

Comment: I would tend to say that space-constrained browsers are more likely to flush the localStorage. If a user is visiting many sites that use localStorage, this may happen soon even on desktop browsers. If I'm not mistaken, that's even part of the localStorage specification. On the other hand, desktop users are IMO more likely to flush their cookies, since that option is easier to reach and some have been trained for years to flush cookies "against advertisers"; some browsers and addons explicitly support that behavior. So, overall, it's a wash I'd say.